# DataGrid sorting with auto generated columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created a DataGrid control, that binds to a DynamicItemCollection (implements ITypedList). For some reason I can't sort the columns by clicking the headers (they are not even clickable). 
For my collection I used the following

http://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/auto-generating-datagrid-columns-from-dynamicobjects

And my xaml is the following

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource={Binding Data}/>
```

What am I missing? Is it the dynamic data? How can I get it to sort?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Declare this in your code behind

```
public bool CanUserSort { get; set; }
```

Attribute usage
Refer this part in your aspx for datagrid tag

```
<object CanUserSort="bool" .../>
```

You can make true, false condition. Since by default its true you can sort the columns.

Comment: I am not sure how to use that, just for the record I am using MVVM

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a old post but after some researches its appear that is really simple : the original link isn't longer available so there is a way to see the [remeirs blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160828173518/http://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/auto-generating-datagrid-columns-from-dynamicobjects)

so based on those blog you can now have a Datagrid autogenerated from dynamicObject (usefull to hydrate object with file content like CSV for exemple)

```
<DataGrid 
ItemsSource="{Binding Instance_of_DynamicItemCollection_ForDynamicObject }"
CanUserAddRows="False"
IsReadOnly="True"
SelectionUnit="Cell"
SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

but effectively you cant autoSort items like you would be able to do in a Datagrid and adding CanUserSortColumns="True" dont work !

there is the very simple solution :

Adding AutoGeneratingColumn event to the Datagrid

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Instance_of_DynamicItemCollection_ForDynamicObject }"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    SelectionUnit="Cell"
    AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
    SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

and in the code behind :

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Column.CanUserSort = true;
        }
```

here is some documentation about this eventHandler
[Datagrid AutogeneratingColumn event from microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/customize_autogenerated_columns)